# LAME bitrate and lowpass filters

Tags: mp3, filter, encoding, bitrate

Is there a formula or chart that specifies what lowpass filter LAME will automatically invoke for certain bitrates? I've looked around the net and can't find anything on this.

And is there a specific logic that dictates said formula or chart, besides just listening tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Lame preset settings]

Source: 
http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=LAME#Recommended_settings_details

Deeper source(code):
https://github.com/rbrito/lame/blob/origin/libmp3lame/lame.c#L211

**Update**:

`--preset insane` seems to be using a lowpass filter as well...
see [LAME: Why is a lowpass filter used with --preset insane](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/38109)

Comment: `--preset insane` seems to be using a lowpass filter as well... see http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/38109/lame-why-is-a-lowpass-filter-used-with-preset-insane

Comment: Since it's been over a year, and this is the first answer, I'm going to mark it as accepted, lest I forget. But I would prefer you add your comment to the answer proper, and would love if you could find anything about WHY they use those particular filters.

Comment: No idea, you could check this thread https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,106868.msg874354.html#msg874354